# ajax call progress bar/progress status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using an ajax call and i need to display some progres status inside my text box. Here is my ajax call.

```
<input type="text" name="cm" id="cm" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#cm').blur(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url: "/validatecm/"+cmnumber,
            cache:false,
            async:false,
            data:cmnumber,
            success: function(data) {
                alert (data)
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to show some progress status iside my text box while doing this AJAX call.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  SO doesn't do your work for you, SO helps solve existing problems.  Include your HTML/CSS/JS and possibly a jsfiddle.

Comment: You can't show the progress of a synchronous request, and the progress event only tracks the progress of an upload, not a basic ajax request.

Comment: You can show a spinner, but it will not spin while the request is being made if it is synchronous.

Comment: Found this one.. http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

Answer (score 2):

You can have something like this. AJAX is meant to be asynchronous. I don't find the use-case of this to be synchronous. So, removing the `async` flag.

```
$('#cm').blur(function(){
    $(this).next("img").show();
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url: "/validatecm/"+cmnumber,
        cache:false,
        // async:false,
        data:cmnumber,
        success: function(data) {
               alert (data);
               $(this).next("img").hide();
        }
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data) }
    }
}
```

A small simulation of the above script would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").blur(function(){
        $(this).next("img").show();
        var a = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            a.next("img").hide();
            a.val("AJAX Load Complete...");
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/QS3RC/).**

Comment: However, since the ajax is synchronous, there's a good chance the browser will lock up before the first line goes into effect.

Comment: @KevinB I don't get you... AJAX is asynchronous...

Comment: Not if you add `async: false`

Comment: Thanks. Will update that in the answer...